# Flask Mongoengine filter a query

Tags: mongodb, flask, flask-mongoengine

I'm using Mongoengine in my flask application and I'm trying to filter a simple query.
My document name is Event and it has the following fields:

- user (ReferenceDocument)
- category (ReferenceDocument)
- type (StringField)
- start_time (DateField)

My goal is to get the last 30 events of given user, filter it based on category & type and then count the filtered results.
My attempt was:

```
    grades = {}
    events = Event.objects(user=user).order_by('-start_time')[:30]
    for category in user.categories:
        grade = 0
        for event_type in eEvents:
            grade += (events(category=category, type=event_type.name).count(
                with_limit_and_skip=True)) * event_type.value
        grades[category.name] = grade
```

So the problem is that the query (2nd line in code) doesn't limit the results and I get all the events of the user. When I use the count method after filtering the query, it does limit the count to 30.

By the way, any idea of a better way for doing it using mongoengine functionality?

Thanks

Comment: What documentation are you following?

Comment: @D.SM https://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html